# How to check a value exists in which table in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have two tables with identical columns, say Table A and Table B and both have column ID. I have a value of ID 'ABC'. How will I check ABC exists in ID column of which table? I need output as the table name.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'A' as table_name FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE id = 'ABC')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE id = 'ABC')
```

`DUAL` is a kind of placeholder you can use, if you don't have a table to select from.

Answer (score 0):

```
select tab from (
  select 'A' tab, count(*) n from tabA where id = 'ABC'
  union all 
  select 'B' tab, count(*) n from tabB where id = 'ABC'
) where n > 0;
```

Comment: Don't use `count()`, if you can use `exists()`. No need to read more rows than necessary.